# Help with an exercise on the cardinality of the set of formulae of a First-Order Language.

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, cardinals

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first order language consisting of:

- $P_i$ predicate symbols, $f_j$ function symbols & $c_k$ constant symbols indexed respectively by th sets $I,J$ & $K$.  Furthermore the arity function that assigns each predicate and function symbol to a positive integer.
- A countable infinite set of variables, $X$.
- The logical connectives: $\neg,\vee$ and universal quantifier $\forall$.

If $L$ is the set of formulas of $\mathcal{L}$, show that $|L|=\max\{|X|,|I|,|J|,|K|\}$.

I think this is meant to be a straightforward exercise but the only argument I can come up with is very tedious and am not too confident about it, so I think there must be a better argument or can anyone improve the argument I have presented below to make it less laborious.  Also please let me know of any errors and how to correct them. Should I maybe use a Gödel style numbering argument and construct an explicit map(but won't this work for only countable languages)?  Also I have not bothered about parentheses and commas in the language, is this fine or do I need to count them as well and if so how? Thanks in advance.

Put $T$ to be the set of all terms of $\mathcal{L}$ and $T_0$ to be all the variable and constant symbols, so $|T_0|=\max\{|X|,|K|\}$.  Then for each $f_j$ and $n\geq 1$, define $Y_{f_j,n-1}:=\{f_j(x_1,...,x_{ar(f_j)}|x_1,...,x_{ar(f_j)}\in T_{n-1}\}$ and $T_n:=T_{n-1}\cup(\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}Y_{f_j,n-1})$.

Now the surjection, $(T_{n-1})^{ar(f_j)}\rightarrow Y_{f_j,n-1}$ defined by $(x_1,...,x_{ar(f_j)})\mapsto f_j(x_1,...,x_{ar(f_j)})$ implies that $|Y_{f_j,n-1}|\leq|T_{n-1}|$, and by induction we get, $|T_{n}|=|T_{n-1}|+|\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}Y_{f_j,n-1}|=|T_{n-1}|+|J|.|T_{n-1}|=\max\{|X|,|J|,|K|\}$.  Thus we have $|T|=|\bigcup\limits_{n<\omega}T_n|\leq\aleph_o.\max\{|X|,|J|,|K|\}=\max\{|X|,|J|,|K|\}$ and as the reverse inequality is obvious we have $|T|=\max\{|X|,|J|,|K|\}$.

Then for each $P_i$ define $Z_{P_i}:=\{P(t_1,...,t_{ar(P_i)})|t_1,...,t_{ar(P_i)}\in T\}$.

So as $Z_{P_i}\subset T^{ar(P_i)}$, we have $|Z_{P_i}|\leq |T|$, therefore the cardinality of the set of atomic formulae, $|L_0|=|\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}Z_{P_i}|\leq |I|.\max\{|X|,|K|,|J|\}=\max\{|X|,|K|,|J|,|I|\}$.

Now for $n\geq1$ define recursively:

- $L_{n,\neg}:=\{\neg\varphi|\varphi\in L_{n-1}\}$,
- $L_{n,\vee}:=\{\varphi\vee\psi|\varphi,\psi\in L_{n-1}\}$,
- $L_{n,\forall}:=\{\forall x\varphi|\varphi\in L_{n-1}\}$  and
- $L_n:=L_{n,\neg}\cup L_{n,\vee}\cup L_{n,\forall}$.

Then as the surjections, $L_{n-1}\rightarrow L_{n,\neg}$ (resp. $L_{n,\forall}$) defined by $\varphi\mapsto \neg\varphi$ (resp. $\forall x\varphi$) and $(L_{n-1})^2\rightarrow L_{n,\vee}$ defined by $(\varphi,\psi)\mapsto\varphi\vee\psi$; implies that
$|L_{n-1}|=|L_{n,\neg}|=|L_{n,\vee}|=|L_{n,\forall}|$.  By induction we can then conclude that

$|L|=|\bigcup\limits_{n<\omega}L_n|\leq\aleph_0.|L_n|=\aleph_0.\max\{|X|,|I|,|J|,|K|\}=\max\{|X|,|I|,|J|,|K|\}$ and as the reverse inequality is is quite apparent, so the exercise is done.

Comment: I suspect you're supposed to already know, and just use, the fact that if $X_1,...,X_n$ are sets at least one of which is infinite, then the set of finite strings from $X_1\cup ...\cup X_n$ has cardinality $\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$. This in turn amounts to the fact that if $\kappa$ is infinite then $\kappa^{<\omega}:=\bigcup_{m\in\omega}\kappa^m=\kappa$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I've used that basic fact of infinite cardinals repeatedly  but that alone is not enough to infer the result. So to get $L$, I first had to find $T$, which is a bit of a rigmarole, with all the maps I had to define  and induction - or is this just inevitable  because of the recursive definition of terms and formulas? It took me a while to think of $Y_{f_j,n}$ and this seems more tedious than the average induction on complexity (for instance in Łoś theorem it's proof is neat), or maybe I'm just being a bit slow? Also is my proof above all correct?